# C++ Unknown stack overflow even after moving large array to the heap

Tags: c++, pointers, recursion, stack-overflow, access-violation

I am counting the number of comparisons made by the quick sort's partition function for increasing n sizes of arrays and have run into an issue. When we enter the sortFirstMiddleLast function I run into stack overflow and Mem Access Violation errors. I have the array that is being sorted created within the heap and the function is called within the iterations of another recursive function call but the recursive call should terminate and the exception is thrown on the very first iteration.

```
//QuickSort Algorithm using the middle element of the array as the pivot

#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

void sortFirstMiddleLast(int*, int, int, int);
int partition(int*, int, int, int*);
void quickSort(int*, int, int, int*);

int main()
{
    clock_t start, stop;
    double totalTime;
    int arrSizeArr[13] = { 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024, 2048, 8192, 16384 };

    for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++)
    {
        int size = arrSizeArr[i];
        int* arr = new int[size];
        
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            arr[j] = (double)(size - j);
        }

        int first = 0;
        int last = size - 1;
        int* quickComp = new int(0);

        cout << "QuickSort w/ Pivot as Middle: " << endl;
        start = clock();
        quickSort(arr, first, last, quickComp);
        stop = clock();
        cout << "# of Comparisons: " << *quickComp << endl;

        totalTime = static_cast<double>(stop - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
        cout << "Run Time: " << totalTime << endl;

        delete quickComp;
        delete[] arr;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void quickSort(int* arr, int first, int last, int* quickComp)
{
    if (first < last)
    {
        int pivotIndex = partition(arr, first, last, quickComp);

        quickSort(arr, first, pivotIndex - 1, quickComp);
        quickSort(arr, pivotIndex - 1, last, quickComp);
    }
}

void sortFirstMiddleLast(int* arr, int first, int mid, int last)
{
    int temp;

    if (arr[first] > arr[mid])
    {
        temp = arr[first];
        arr[first] = arr[mid];
        arr[mid] = temp;
    }
    if (arr[mid] > arr[last])
    {
        temp = arr[mid];
        arr[mid] = arr[last];
        arr[last] = temp;
    }
    if (arr[first] > arr[mid])
    {
        temp = arr[first];
        arr[first] = arr[mid];
        arr[mid] = temp;
    }
}

int partition(int* arr, int first, int last, int* quickComp)
{
    int mid = first + (last - first) / 2;
    sortFirstMiddleLast(arr, first, mid, last);

    int temp = arr[mid];
    arr[mid] = arr[last - 1];
    arr[last - 1] = temp;
    int pivotIndex = last - 1;
    int pivot = arr[pivotIndex];

    int indexLeft = first + 1;
    int indexRight = last - 2;

    bool done = false;
    
    while (!done)
    {
        while (arr[indexLeft] < pivot)
        {
            indexLeft++;
            *quickComp = *quickComp + 1;
        }
        while (arr[indexRight] > pivot)
        {
            indexRight--;
            *quickComp = *quickComp + 1;
        }
        if (indexLeft < indexRight)
        {
            temp = arr[indexLeft];
            arr[indexLeft] = arr[indexRight];
            arr[indexRight] = temp;

            indexLeft++;
            indexRight--;
            *quickComp = *quickComp + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            done = true;
        }
    }

    temp = arr[pivotIndex];
    arr[pivotIndex] = arr[indexLeft];
    arr[indexLeft] = temp;

    pivotIndex = indexLeft;

    return pivotIndex;
}
```

From what I understand using the "new" operator should allocate memory on the heap for the array so as the size n of the array increases it should not cause a stack issue. The only other thing I could think of would be a non terminating recursive call but I don't understand why it throw an exception on the very first call and why it makes it through the quickSort and partition functions but throws the exception within sortFirstMiddleLast. If anybody can explain this to me or let me know if I am way off base in my thinking I would really appreciate it.[Stack exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OrbPR.png) [mem access exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V84Vo.png)

Comment: Q: From what I understand using the "new" operator should allocate memory on the heap.  A: That's correct.  Q: The only other thing I could think of would be a non terminating recursive call.  A: Yup - that's the first place I'd look!  SUGGESTION: Step through your code under the debugger!  In particular, break at the very first line of your recursive call, and step through from there.

Comment: First problem you are not doing DRY (don't repeat yourself) all those swaps should be a subroutine, then all potential problems with wrong code in those parts goes away.

Comment: The second recursive `quickSort` call should probably pass `pivotIndex + 1`. Otherwise, with `last == first + 2`, you are calling `quickSort(first, last)` over and over.

Comment: Use a debugger.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions I will definitely create a swap function to rule that out and then I’ll step through the debugger (as I should have done from the get go) to try and find where my recursion logic isn’t adding up. Sometimes you really need people to point out the obvious for you to realize that you need to drill the fundamentals even more lol. I’ll update if I find my issue. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @JacobJones you will see if Igor's response is true if you look at the call stack.

Comment: It was exactly as Igor said, that was the issue and it executes no problem now. I feel pretty embarrassed at how long I have sat here trying to figure this out there's really no reason why I shouldn't have been able to. Thank you all for the help, I really do appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

After partitioning at pivot point, this algorithm is keeping the `pivotIndex - 1` as common element in both partitions, which is not expected. It should be `first` to `pivotInxex - 1` and then `pivotIndex` to `last`. Following code should work fine:

```
quickSort(arr, first, pivotIndex - 1, quickComp);
quickSort(arr, pivotIndex, last, quickComp);
```